# counting the numbers of objects using video steam

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently working on a game that involve the use openCV library using video streaming using Python as a programming language. The game consists of a twelve QR markers (objects). How can I count the number of objects (fiducial tags or QR code) on a video stream using OpenCV (cv2 library). The following function calls a library function which reads the QR code and creates a frame for each marker with the use or Augmented reality:

```
def readAndDetect(image):

    global markerDictionary
    markers = detect_markers(image)

    for marker in markers:
        marker.highlite_marker(image)
        #Create a dictionary key == MarkerId , Values: (center)]

        markerDictionary[marker.id] = marker.center
        print(markerDictionary)
    cv2.imshow('Test Frame', image)
```

My code keeps generating objects i.e. keeps duplicating and counting the markers. I though of using a History to keep track of the objects to limit the duplicate. Is there any way I can implement to limit the duplicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a history which maintains and keep tracking the number of objects as follows:

```
global StringPair

    markers = detect_markers(image)    

    # to remove duplicate 
    refined_markers = dict( [ ( marker.id, marker ) for marker in markers if self.checkForExistance(marker.id) ]  )
    # And then Assign the values to the markers As result, markers has no duplicate     
    markers = [ refined_markers[idx] for idx in refined_markers  ]

    # create history
    self.history.insert(0, markers )
    #print (">>>", history)
    if len(self.history) > 30:
        self.history.pop()

    # get all markers from history
    #this will be my list for stuff
    all_markers = {}
    for entry in reversed(self.history):
        for marker in entry:
            all_markers[marker.id] = marker

    #Generate and highlight the markers          
    for idx in all_markers:
        marker = all_markers[idx]
        marker.highlite_marker(image)        

    # Number of detected markers        
    self.count2 = len(all_markers)
```